# Which code is better in terms of speed and processing?

Tags: python

both of codes is same purpose :-
Pig Latin is a language game, where you move the first letter of the word to the end and add "ay." So "Python" becomes "ythonpay."

```
 pyg = 'ay'

 original = raw_input('Enter a word:')

 if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
      word= original.lower()
      first= word[0]
      new_word= word +first +  pyg
      new_word= new_word[1:len(new_word)]
      print new_word

 else:
     print 'empty'
```

or this

```
 user = raw_input("what is the word you want to play with:").lower()

 if user.isalpha() and len(user) > 0:
    print user[1:] + user[0:1] + "ay"
 else:
      print "please enter valid name!"
```

Comment: Run each of them 10000 times and compare how long they take.

Comment: function 1: 0.572109937668                                                                      function 2:0.469521999359                                                                                         is this small diffrence matter in the performae of the code

Answer (score 1):

With a bit help from the `timeit` library, I came to the conclusion that the second way is faster (it runs your code thousands of times also suggested in the comments).  The codes are both very similar codes while the second one is more concise. For further reference, if you want to test which code is better in terms of speed. Here's how you should do it:

```
import timeit

def func1():
    original = 'spam'
    pyg = 'ay'
    if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
        word= original.lower()
        first= word[0]
        new_word= word +first +  pyg
        new_word= new_word[1:len(new_word)]
        s= new_word

    else:
        s= ('empty') 

def func2():
    user = 'spam'.lower()

    if user.isalpha() and len(user) > 0:
        s = user[1:] + user[0:1] + "ay"
    else:
        s = "please enter valid name!" 

a=timeit.timeit(func1)
b=timeit.timeit(func2)
print "function 1: {0}\nfunction 2:{1}".format(a,b)
```

As you can see, this isn't exactly the same as your code, I got rid of `raw_input()` and replaced it with a default string ("spam" in this case). and instead of `print`, I temporarily saved it in a variable called `s`. Both of the modifications are necessary, else the result will vary.

Comment: thank you ,  can you help and give advice how to write a good and simple code ... im  new to programing

Comment: If you wanted even shorter, you can get rid of `and len(user) > 0` since isalpha checks that too. And that I believe, it's the shortest version possible.

Comment: i forgot that .isalpha is only accept alpahpet                                                                 thank you